# Edit Text Box with button on Delphi 7

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

How can I create a textbox with a button inside in delphi 7?
I can't use TButtonedEdit in my delphi 7, not sure if it doens't have this feature yet.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked on www.torry.net?  There are at least four ButtonEdits there.

Comment: JVCL have `TJvComboEdit`, previously one of the controls of 'RX Library'.